# See output of a sql query while plugin installation in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, sql

Doing wordpress plugin development, I am creating a table (while installing the plugin) with the following string:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE (query skipped)..."; /*someting*/
```

For example: I have this

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'my_plugin_install' );
function my_plugin_install(){

$sql = "CREATE TABLE (query skipped)..."; /*someting*/
echo $sql;
}
```

The problem is there is some error with this query and and I want to see the output of $sql using php.

But the above code doesn't echo anything when plugin is installed. Any way to see the ouput?

```
Details: 
function my_plugin_install(){

   global $wpdb, $current_user;;

   //getting the musician/user rating keys
    global $k11, $k12, $k13, $k14, $k21, $k22, $k23, $k24;

   $fabprofile_table_name=$wpdb->prefix."fabulous_profile";

   $fabulous_profile_version = "2.0";

   //mid= music user id
   //uid = general user id
   //creating the ratings table
   $sql = "CREATE TABLE $fabprofile_table_name (

  mid tinyint(9) NOT NULL,

  uid tinyint(9) NOT NULL,

  $k11 tinyint(1) NOT NULL, $k12 tinyint(1) NOT NULL,$k13 tinyint(1) NOT NULL, $k14 tinyint(1) NOT NULL,

  $k21 tinyint(1) NOT NULL, $k22 tinyint(1) NOT NULL, $k23 tinyint(1) NOT NULL, $k24 tinyint(1) NOT NULL

);";



   require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );

   dbDelta( $sql );
   $wpdb->show_errors(); 
    echo $sql;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could insert a

```
$wpdb->show_errors();
```

to output the errors in your query.

Also you need to input that sql into

```
dbDelta($sql)
```

did you miss that?

Comment: I am running the $sql query with this:  dbDelta( $sql );          It doesn't help :(..

Comment: No output with the show_errors()? Also the debug is set to true right?

Comment: nope, I don't see any output. It just shows The plugin generated ** characters of unexpected output during activation. Is there any way to see that unexpectedd output?

Comment: Did you put a global $wpdb; before your query? And also, did you include wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php ?

Comment: yes,let me show youy

Comment: CREATE TABLE $fabprofile_table_name -> CREATE TABLE".$fabprofile_table_name".( should should work

Comment: Can't we see the $sql output on wordpress backend plugin installation or save $sql somewhere?

Comment: you could obviously just echo it, but you need to use proper string concatenation either with "." or with curly braces

Comment: echo doesn't output anything if it is done inside the plugin installation function..you can check it urself..:(. And I can obviously use somthing like file_put_contents() to see the $sql...but I wanted to see the output somehow..

Comment: Ah I see the problem, maybe just look into your php error log it will likely show the error from the query
Or you you put the $wpdb->last_query  into a log file
and the $wpdb->last_result

Comment: where is the php error log?

Comment: you can get the location from phpinfo() and then looking for error_log provided you use apache2

Comment: oh, thnx..i can see the log